# Where to find the man page for command "unminimize"?

Tags: 20.04

I am using a Ubuntu docker image which is minimized to develop my project.
I hope to run command `unminimize` to bring some functions back to the container.
But I can not find man page of this command.
I tried to install `man-db`.
But when I run `man minimize`, it complains that

> No manual entry for unminimize

Where can I find man page for this command?

Comment: Not really a man page for unminimize, but it might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1329222/231142

Comment: @Terrance Yes, that helped me a lot. I can make it to run `unminimize` from Dockerfile. I asked for a man page because I would like to know more about this command. Such as options, syntax and so on.

Comment: I am not using docker at the moment, so I cannot see the commands, but sometimes apps simply do not have a man page as the developer may not have felt one was needed.  Have you tried `unminimize --help`?

Comment: @Terrance Yes, I did. `unminimize --help` will not print help message. It behaves just like normal `unminimize`.

Comment: It's just a simple shell script, located at "/usr/local/sbin/unminimize" in container